# Counting characters between 2 specified words in a string

Tags: javascript, character

This is my text string:

```
0000> hello world <0000
```

I want to count the characters between "0000>" and "<0000".

Comment: Just for the record, if you are trying to parse an xml  you shoud use a parser, [not regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
s = "0000> hello my name is james, whats yours? <0000";
s.match(/0000>(.*?)<0000/)[1].length // returns 38;
```

But then again, so will this :-)

```
s.length - 10; // returns 38
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, something like this would count everything (including spaces) between 0000> and <0000:

```
'0000> hello my name is james, whats yours? <0000'
  .split(/0000>|<0000/g)[1].length; //=> 38
```

Or

```
'0000> hello my name is james, whats yours? <0000'
     .replace(/0000>|<0000/g,'').length; //=> 38
```

Comment: you don't need the last split(''). Strings have a length property of their own.

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
function count(string) {
  var match = /0000>(.*)<0000/g.exec(string);

  if (match.length > 1) {
    return match[1].trim().length;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

alert (count("0000> hello my name is james, whats yours? <0000"));
```

And the jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pSJGk/1/

Comment: unfortunately i still have a problem.  this is my string:   <svg width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <rect id="svg_1" height="134" width="134" y="95" x="96" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000"/>
  <text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="middle" font-family="verdana" font-size="24" id="svg_2" y="122" x="112" stroke="#6E6E6E" fill="none">really?</text>
 </g>
</svg>                i want to perform the calculations on this string and it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: the word i want to count in this example is the work "really?".  Its between the words "none"> and </text>

Comment: If you want to parse xml use a parser, [not regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
var str = " 0000> hello my name is james, whats yours? <0000",
    start = "0000>",
    end = "<0000",
    between = str.substring(str.indexOf(start) + start.length, str.indexOf(end)).length;

console.log(between);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZdByu/1/).

This doesn't, however, trim the white-space from after the first match, or from before the second. This could be altered, of course, to match any given string delimiters by simply changing the variables.

References:

- [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
- [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length).
- [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

Answer (score 0):

```
function getLengthBetween(str,startStr,stopStr) {
  var startPos = str.indexOf(startStr);
  if(startPos == -1) {
    return 0;
  }
  var startOffset = startPos+startStr.length;
  var stopPos  = str.indexOf(stopStr,startOffset);
  if(stopPos == -1) {
    stopPos = str.length;
  }
  return stopPos-startOffset;
}
```

Usage:

```
getLengthBetween("0000> hello my name is james, whats yours? <0000","0000>","<0000");
```

Comment: unfortunately i still have a problem. this is my string: <svg width="500" height="500" xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg">; <!-- Created with SVG-edit - svg-edit.googlecode.com --> <g> <title>Layer 1</title> <rect id="svg_1" height="134" width="134" y="95" x="96" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000"/> <text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="middle" font-family="verdana" font-size="24" id="svg_2" y="122" x="112" stroke="#6E6E6E" fill="none">really?</text> </g> </svg> i want to perform the calculations on this string and it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: well I dont see the original 'strings' "0000>" and "<0000".. which text are you trying to find the length of in this string?

Comment: actually that was an example. the original strings are fill="none">   and </text> respectively. its at the end of the string i just posted. in this example i need to count the characters of the word "really?".

Comment: its an xml output i think. does that make it any different?

Comment: assuming that string is assigned to variable 'myString' .. i tried getLengthBetween(myString,'fill="none">','</text>') and it gave me 7 .. as long as its of type 'string' it should work (even though it looks like xml) .. can you do an alert(typeof(myString)) ? it should say 'string' .. otherwise none of the answers here would work

Comment: unfortunately i am just now starting getting into javascript? can you do a jsfiddle demo???? that will help me a lot!!  only if you have time. thanks for all the answers anyway.

Comment: it really depends where that string is coming from.. are you seeing it in a console.log ? .. it is possible that this is not a string value afterall.. try adding alert(typeof(str)) on the first line of my function

Comment: nicholas.kyriakides@hotmail.com

Comment: @NikolasKyriakides check your inbox